# Using VBA to add tabs to a multipage useform in excel

Tags: vba, excel, userform, multipage

I need to find the VBA code to add x number of tabs to a multipage in a userform in excel. I can manually add tabs if I use the visual basic editor, but I want to be able to dynamically add/delete tabs using VBA during runtime.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Tabs` in a `MultiPage1` are called `Pages` and you can add them using

```
MultiPage1.Pages.Add
```

You can use the above code in a loop to add pages. Please refer to Excel's inbuilt help for more details

**Edit**:

Just saw the 2nd part of the question. To delete, say the 1st page use this

```
MultiPage1.Pages.Remove (0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add/remove them dymanically to the form permanently with

```
Sub Test()
Dim vbComp As Object
Dim objCntrl As Control
Set vbComp = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("UserForm1")
Set objCntrl = vbComp.Designer.Controls("MultiPage1")
'add page
objCntrl.Pages.Add
'remove page
objCntrl.Pages.Remove (1)
End Sub
```